# Incorrect frustum culling with center/half-size AABB

Tags: xna, c#, culling, frustum, aabb

I'm trying to implement an axis-aligned bounding box with center/half-size instead of min/max. And I have some problems when it comes to create a method to detect if the aabb is visible or not.

I try to do the same as on this website at "Method 5": http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/view-frustum-culling/. I'm trying to implement this formula:

> return dot3(center + extent * signFlip, plane) > -plane.w;

But it doesn't work at all and I don't find what's going wrong. Objects in my scene seems to appear and disappear in a strange way, sometimes appears when I'm not watching them or disappears when frustum faces them (I look at draw calls to determine if the isVisible test returns true or false).

Here is my code:

The Axis-aligned bounding box

```
public sealed class AxisAlignedBox
{
    public Vector3 Center;
    public Vector3 HalfSize;
}
```

The method in the frustum that tests if the aabb is visible or not:

```
public bool Intersects(AxisAlignedBox aabb)
    {
        Vector3 v;
        float d;

        Vector3.Multiply(ref aabb.HalfSize, ref _signPlane[0], out v);
        Vector3.Add(ref aabb.Center, ref v, out v);
        Vector3.Dot(ref v, ref _planes[0].Normal, out d);
        if (d > -_planes[0].D) return true;

        Vector3.Multiply(ref aabb.HalfSize, ref _signPlane[1], out v);
        Vector3.Add(ref aabb.Center, ref v, out v);
        Vector3.Dot(ref v, ref _planes[1].Normal, out d);
        if (d > -_planes[1].D) return true;

        Vector3.Multiply(ref aabb.HalfSize, ref _signPlane[2], out v);
        Vector3.Add(ref aabb.Center, ref v, out v);
        Vector3.Dot(ref v, ref _planes[2].Normal, out d);
        if (d > -_planes[2].D) return true;

        Vector3.Multiply(ref aabb.HalfSize, ref _signPlane[3], out v);
        Vector3.Add(ref aabb.Center, ref v, out v);
        Vector3.Dot(ref v, ref _planes[3].Normal, out d);
        if (d > -_planes[3].D) return true;

        Vector3.Multiply(ref aabb.HalfSize, ref _signPlane[4], out v);
        Vector3.Add(ref aabb.Center, ref v, out v);
        Vector3.Dot(ref v, ref _planes[4].Normal, out d);
        if (d > -_planes[4].D) return true;

        Vector3.Multiply(ref aabb.HalfSize, ref _signPlane[5], out v);
        Vector3.Add(ref aabb.Center, ref v, out v);
        Vector3.Dot(ref v, ref _planes[5].Normal, out d);
        if (d > -_planes[5].D) return true;

        return false;
    }
```

_signPlane is an array of Vector3 using the following formula and applied for each plane once per frame when the frustum is updated:

```
        public static void Sign(ref Vector3 v, out Vector3 result)
    {
        result.X = Math.Sign(v.X);
        result.Y = Math.Sign(v.Y);
        result.Z = Math.Sign(v.Z);
    }
```

Comment: It is hard to say without the full code. But difference could be in how you treat _plane[i].D. I.e. one can write plane equation as Ax+By+Cz = D or like Ax+By+Cz + D = 0 in this case those Ds have different sign for same plane.

Comment: I'm sorry to haven't provided enough code. The code I added in my question is all what I wrote. Anything else is provided by XNA (Vector3, ...). To get the frustum plane I use a class called BoundingFrustum. Each frame I give the viewProj matrix to the BoundingFrustum and it computes the plane. I don't know how it computes plane and D.

Comment: looking at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.plane.aspx I see that D they use is negative distance along the plane. So, your formulae are fine if plane normals point outwards. However, if they have opposite direction (i.e. if they point inside frustum) you may try to change **d > -_planes[0].D** to **d > _planes[0].D** (or, equivalently, negate normal, but not both).